# How can I align text in the same tag differently?

Tags: html, css, text, center, text-align

So I have some text in-between an h2 tag, and I basically want to have the entire h2 tag centered on the page. But I also want to have some text on a second line, that is aligned to the right.

So it would look something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS ***flexbox*** for a clean and simple solution.

```css
main {                          /* 1 */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

h2 {
  display: inline-flex;         /* 2 */
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
}

h2>span {
  margin-left: auto;            /* 3 */
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h2>
    WebsiteName<span>.com</span>
  </h2>
</main>
```

Notes:

1. Block level container; gives `h2` the space to be horizontally centered.
2. Make `h2` an inline-level container, so the box is only as wide as the content. This allows the first and second lines to align right.
3. Align second line to the right.

---

Alternative method, using ***absolute positioning***, based on feedback in the comments:

```css
h2 {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

h2>span {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  WebsiteName<span>.com</span>
</h2>
```

Comment: This works great! Except I have one problem, I would like to have the position of my h2 element as absolute. Because if its not set to absolute then it kinda messes up my websites layout.

Comment: Is it possible to make the .com closer to WebsiteName?

Comment: Yes. You can adjust the `line-height` or use a negative `margin`: https://jsfiddle.net/kcdfdao3/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can try the  tag or the float property with the defined class.

Answer (score 0):

by adding the following syntax:

```
.class_name tag_name
```